# SSH passphrase fails twice, but always works on the third time

Tags: linux, ssh

Since some time ago, I started failing to introduce by SSH passphrase correctly in my terminal, or so I thought. It will always ask, I will type it, it would ask again, I re-type it, then a third time, and it finally works.

Until I tried writing my passphrase elsewhere and copying it, then pasting it in the Terminal. It will still fail twice!

What could cause this? Some commands don't cause this. `git fetch` works with a single try, but `git push` fails twice, as well as `ssh`.

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple instances of ssh-agent running in the background? Or maybe one that interferes with your window manager's built-in agent/keychain?

Comment: Any kind of network load-balancing between you and the server?

Comment: Only one instance of ssh-agent seems to be running. No idea if something is interfering with my wm (i3wm btw). I also have no clue if there's any load-balancing going on, but why would it affect only some commands?

Comment: I have the same thing. One way to debug it is to add verbosity to the ssh command:
`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv" git push`
This shows for me that it successfully auths with github the first try, but then for some reason requires it again. If I find out why, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have worked around this quirk by running `ssh-add` on each terminal. That's naturally not ideal and not as safe.

Comment: Any news on that one?